# which notion of provability in Turing's paper 1936?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, turing-machines, decidability

In Turing's article 1936 [https://www.cs.virginia.edu/~robins/Turing_Paper_1936.pdf](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/%7Erobins/Turing_Paper_1936.pdf)
Turing provides a proof in §11 p.259 for the Hilbert decision problem "Entscheidungsproblem".

p. 259 he says "I propose, therefore, to show that there can be no general process for
determining whether a given formula U of the functional calculus K is
provable"

For that, he constructs for each Turing machine M a formula Un(M) p. 260, and proves in Lemmas 1 and 2 that

"M ends up printing the 0 symbol" iff Un(M) is provable.

I understand the notion of Hilbert formal proof of a formula F in a theory T,
in standard notation T |- F .

I do not understand which signature L he is using for constructing Un(M) as a first order formula ?

And when he says "provable", which theory T in this langage L is he refering to ?

What is to be meant by "Hilbert functional calculus K" in relation with modern presentations of proof theory in the context of first order theories ?

Comment: Usual predicate calculus in Hilbert-style form, e.g. Hilbert-Ackermann textbooks and Godel's papers.

Comment: In Hilbert-style deduction system, one starts with a first order theory T, and deduces formulas from T and the deduction rules. What is the theory T in that particular case ?

Comment: See Turing (1936): "If the notation of the Hilbert functional calculus..." and the reference is to Hilbert & Ackermann's [Principles of Mathematical Logic (1928)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_of_Mathematical_Logic) at page 259. See [here](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Principles_of_Mathematical_Logic/45ZGMjV9vfcC), page 65: it is what we call today first-order logic.

Comment: See [Entscheidungsproblem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entscheidungsproblem): "a challenge posed by David Hilbert and Wilhelm Ackermann in 1928.[1] The problem asks for an algorithm that considers, as input, a statement and answers "Yes" or "No" according to whether the statement is universally valid, i.e., valid in every structure satisfying the axioms." By Godel's Completeness Theorem for predicate calculus, this is equivalent to asking whether the formula is provable in the predicate calculus.

Comment: Thus, Turing's argument is: to "map" the functioning of the UM into predicate calculus and translate the halting question into a formula of predicate calculus: IF we have a decision procedure for predicate calculus, this procedure will give us a procedure for deciding the halting question, which is not.

Comment: For a modern version, see BBJ, [Computability and Logic (5th ed, 2007)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Computability_and_Logic/kKPA1DF-g44C) **Ch.11 The Undecidability of First-Order Logic**, page 126: "We are going to show how, given the machine table or flow chart or other suitable presentation of a Turing machine, and any n, we can effectively write down a finite set of sentences $\Gamma$ and a sentence $D$ such that $\Gamma$ implies $D$ if and only if the machine in question does eventually halt when started with input n, [...]

Comment: that is, when started in its initial state scanning the leftmost of a block of n strokes on an otherwise blank tape. It follows that if the *decision problem* for logical implication could be solved, that is,
if an effective method could be devised that, applied to any finite set of sentences $\Gamma$ and sentence $D$, would in a finite amount of time tell us whether or not $\Gamma$ implies $D$,
then the halting problem for Turing machines could be solved, or in other words, an effective method would exist that, applied to any suitably presented Turing machine and number n, ..."

Comment: I end up understanding by reading more details of the proof of lemma 1 and some parts of the Hilbert book "principles of mathematical logic" : the meaning of "provable" for Turing is "universally provable", or "provable in the void theory" in modern terms.

Comment: Correct, but for a finite number of premises, $\Gamma \vdash D$ is equiv to $\vdash \land_i \gamma_i \to D$ where $\Gamma = \{ \gamma_1, \ldots, \gamma_n \}$